# office-addin-lint prettier MODULE_NOT_FOUND - problem with window path

Tags: reactjs, path, office-addins, git-commit, prettier

```
    [91m[91m×[91m office-addin-lint prettier --files "**/*.{ts,tsx}":[39m
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sebastien'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

i've got this error when i want to commit something.
my path 'C:\Users\sebastien niel....'

something goes wrong with the path, because it stops at the level of "sebastien" and not "sebastien niel"

- OEM : windows 10,
- "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.1.3",
- "prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier --files src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",